# Numeric Input Only, Angular IE11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have an input field that accepts numbers only, however this only works within chrome. When I try the same input field in IE11 it accepts all types of inputs.

```
<input type="number"/>
```

I have also tried with no victory.

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*"/>
```

Any work around for this? IE11 is sure something magical.

Solved myself:

Added

```
<input type="text" (keypress)="isNumberKey($event)"/>
```

And then in my component:

```
  isNumberKey($event) {
    let charCode = ($event.which) ? $event.which : $event.keyCode;
    console.log('Char code is ---> ', charCode);
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
      return false;

    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved similar problem by creating a directive that allows a specific character limit as well as numbers only.

```
appName.directive("limitTo", [function() {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        var limit = parseInt(attrs.limitTo);
        angular.element(elem).on("keypress", function(e) {
            if (this.value.length == limit) {
                if(e.which != 8){
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            }
            if((isNaN(String.fromCharCode(e.charCode)) || e.charCode === 32 || e.charCode === 69) && e.which != 8){
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This will allow you to restrict anything that is not a number (including spaces, 'e', and dashes). Simply add the directive 'limit-to' with a character limit or none at all.

```
<input type="number" limit-to="4">
```

Hope this helps, sorry for the year late response. Cheers!

Comment: e.keyCode is not a viable solution as it does not work in Firefox. e.charCode will work in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close with your second example. This would do the trick:

```
<input type="text" pattern="^[0-9]*$"/>
```

Comment: You're right, i hastily validated your Regex and though that the issue is related to it.

Comment: For the sake of precision, both regex patterns work in Chrome in IE11 when it comes to validating the html form. What they do not do is prevent the input of invalid values.